# Power supply for a LED driver

Tags: transformer, flyback

I'm working on a project in school were I have the [PMP4862 circuit](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/slur512/slur512.pdf) as a reference. Unfortunately the [flyback](http://pdfcast.org/pdf/125-w-flyback-transformer) is no longer available.

**How can I modify the circuit to use available parts?**

I wonder if you know any equivalent flyback or if you can recommend another power supply that can be used for the same LED driver as in PMP4862 and can handle an input voltage between 85-260 V AC. Since I can't just change the transformer without change values on resistors and capacitance on the whole circuit, right?

Feels like I've been searching everywhere without getting wiser :/

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely consider having a go at winding this transformer myself. The spec seems fairly decent: -

[image]

You should be able to find the cores from the usually sources (Ferroxcube, Siemens, Fair-lite to name a few) and you have specs for the inductances which can be translated into numbers of turns. You should know peak currents and be able to decide what gapping may have been applied to prevent core saturation. And most importantly, you have one or two (I presume) lying around at school - reverse engineering this transformer is not too difficult AND you'll learn along the way.

Looking further down the spec it gives you turns ratios and one I quote is 1:0.083 - this is 12:1 in my book but it could be 24:2 of course. It gets easier! The 1:0.055 is likely 18:1. The trickiest bit is working out the core material but maybe the manufacturer will help you. If you know the switching frequency you can pick a suitable core material by looking at the material specifications then this can be double-checked against the inductance and turns specified above to see if the value for A\$_L\$ (inductance factor) ties in with the choice.

Alternatively contact [Premier Magnetics](http://www.premiermag.com/html/product-family/power-magnetics.html): -

[image]

Comment: Tnx for the fast answer but the thought of this project is to install it in a smart streetlight solution so it should be easy to build many of the same circuit so doing it on my own is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Read the last line of my answer "Alternatively contact Premier Magnetics". They have a large number of transformers designed for various switching circuits and with the current spec you have, I'm sure they could engineer it for you and build it for you.